# copy cell from Excel from different sheets to one using Python

Tags: python, excel

I'm new to Python and want to compile values located in the same address from different Excel sheets to a single one. My code, shown below is giving me trouble.
Could you help me please? (the code shown below pretends to copy from one workbook to another, my final code should access many workbooks and compile all desired fields into a single Excel sheet)

```
import openpyxl as opl

wb1 = opl.load_workbook('C:/users/Gabriel/documents/python/python-excel/data1.xlsx')

wb2 = opl.load_workbook('c:/users/Gabriel/documents/python/python-excel/data2.xlsx')
sheet1=wb1.active

sheet2=wb2.active

a1=sheet1['A1']

a2=sheet1['A2']

a3=sheet1['A3']


sheet2['B1']=a1

sheet2['B2']=a2

sheet2['B3']=a3

wb2.save('c:/users/Gabriel/documents/python/python-excel/data2.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome! 
It is really hard to tell what is your problem... Instead of asking for more details, let's exchange information, since you are new to Python that should work better. So... as a first guess - use `sheet1['A1'].value` respectively - for reading and writing.

If you are looking for code that reads Excel files and combine their data. [Here](https://github.com/TeXXaS/dotfiles/blob/linux-user/scripts/report.py) is my example.

As a side note - I've heard that MS is going to use Python as their scripting language!

Comment: Michal Zaborowski, the hyperlink to your example is not working. Could you check it, please?

Comment: Sorry for that - fixed